# check for binary before running a Make rule

Tags: makefile, phpunit

i have this simple rule:

```
.PHONY: test
test: src/*Test.php
    $(PHPUNIT) $?;\
```

it will look trhu the unit tests i have and run phpunit.

I wanted to have something like: (warning, non-valid makefile syntax)

```
ifneq($(HAS_PHPUNIT),)
test: testok
else
test: testbad
endif

testok: src/*Test.php
    $(PHPUNIT) $?;\

testbad:
    echo "test: failed checking for executable file $(PHPUNIT)";\
    echo "      You may need to install phpunit";\
```

i could use the current code and just add `if [ ! -e $(PHPUNIT) ]; then warn; else test it; done` but then if will be overly verbose as it will warn the user once per file.

what's the pattern i'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "make way" to do it is to make your one-time check a separate target itself, and list that as a prerequisite of the targets that you would like to only run after that check happens.  Here's one way you can do it with GNU make:

```
TESTS:=$(wildcard *.test)
TEST_TARGETS=$(patsubst %,run_%,$(TESTS))
.PHONY: test

test: $(TEST_TARGETS)

run_%: check_php_unit
        @echo Running test $(*)

check_php_unit:
        @echo Checking for php unit
```

That is, make a dummy target for each test file that executes that set of tests, then make those targets depend on the `check_php_unit` target.  The commands for `check_php_unit` can do whatever validation you want and then print a warning, or exit with an error code and cause the make run to terminate, or whatever you like.

Comment: think i was overdoing it. the make will fail anyway after the 1st file it tries to run agains phpunit if there's no binary there. there was no need to do all that. but thanks for the better syntax. improved a little based on that.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following makefile

```
.PHONY: check
check:
    @[ -f `which cmake` ] ||  $(error Install cmake first)

.PHONY: check2    
check2:
    @[ -f `which cmake` ] || echo "Install cmake first"

.PHONY: exec
exec: check
    @echo "Compiling executable ..."
    @[ -d ./build ] || mkdir ./build
    @cd ./build; cmake ../src; make
```

While target **check2** works (when cmake exists, i don't get the message "Install cmake first", when it doesn't, i get the message), target **check** always exit even when cmake exists.

So I cannot use target **check** for target **exec**. I have to use target **check2** and, of course, *make* quits because it doesn't find cmake.

I would like *make* to quit before it starts echoing "Compiling executable ...".